# gvim: file list on split window, open in top screen

Tags: vim

I have a split window open in GVIM.
On the bottom window I have a text file open. 
This text file contains a list of files (with full path).

What I would like is a command so that according to my cursor position on a file name in the bottom window, that file will open on the top window. At the moment, when I press g-f it opens it in the bottom window instead of the file list.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I managed to solve it with a macro (copy line, ctrl-w, up, :e and paste). Any better suggestions are welcome!

Comment: CTRL+w CTRL+F is not exactly what you are asking for but might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mapping like this one:

```
nnoremap <F7> :let cf = expand("<cfile>") <bar> wincmd k <bar> execute "e " . cf<CR>
```

1. save the filename under the cursor in a variable,
2. move the cursor to the window above,
3. edit the file.

But what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to do just that: Open within one keystroke the filename under the cursor, but in a top window. Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I hit F7 with filename under cursor and nothing happens.

Comment: What you describe is the exact behavior of `<C-w><C-f>`. The mapping above works for me, though.